# JQgrid datepicker issue?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In my JQgrid where I am using inline cell editing, such that when I tab from one dateCell to another in generates `Uncaught Type error`.

The error is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dpDiv' of undefined jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js:65
```

What I believe is going wrong, is that the keydown event in the datepicker field gets fired and when it executes it finds the `dpDiv` to be null. To overcome this as well, I tried to destroy the keydown event whenever `Tab` key is pressed, but no luck here..

This is what I am doing which generates this error:

```
 afterEditCell: function (id, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
            var cModel = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
            var currCol = cModel[iCol].name;

                var $row = $grid.find('.jqgrow#' + id);
                var $columns = $row.find('td');
                $td = $($columns[iCol]);

                if (isAnyDate(iCol)) {
                $td.find('input').addClass('textBoxStyle').datepicker().keyup(function (e) {
                        var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
                        if (code == 9)
                            $(this).datepicker('destroy');
                    });
                }

});
```

It works fine when mouse click is used for cell navigation!

Help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

May be its not getting the event of keys, try with this one:

instead using `keyup` try using `keypress` or `keydown`

```
if (isAnyDate(iCol)) {
    $td.find('input').addClass('textBoxStyle').datepicker().keydown(function (e) {
       var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
       if (code == 9)
          $(this).datepicker('destroy');
    });
 }
```

or this one:

```
if (isAnyDate(iCol)) {
     $td.find('input').addClass('textBoxStyle').datepicker();
     $(document).on('keydown', '.textBoxStyle', function(e) {
         var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
         if (code == 9)
            $(this).datepicker('destroy');
     });
 }
```

tried in a fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/VMuhK/1/

try this and see if helps.

Comment: Which browser are you using, I am trying it on IE8, and the error persists..tried both!

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle?

Comment: The fiddle does not seem to work, tried it on chrome 23.0.1271.97.

Comment: can you please make a fiddle for it?

Comment: [this is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/VMuhK/) to the fiddle which I ran, no tab key event captured in both the browsers

Comment: this is mine and this is working. have you tested on `ff` or `ie`

Comment: **can you please make a fiddle for it? ** this means your code in fiddle.

Comment: `_doKeyDown:function(a){var b=$.datepicker._getInst(a.target),c=!0,d=b.dpDiv.is(".ui-datepicker-rtl");` this is the line in jquery, on which the error is generated..

Comment: `dpDiv is null or not an object`